# show spinner during angular linking phases

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a view which takes about 3 seconds to render. During that time a user doesn't see anything happening on the page. I tried to add spinner but it doesn't spin, it is just stuck. I assume this is because browser is waiting till JS code is finished and can't have control over spinner until that. So if the reason is exactly that JS code is running for 3 seconds and browser can't do anything during that time how can I optimize that? If I didn't use the framework I could split my code into several chunks and run them with timeout but not sure how I can do that with Angular during its linking phase.

UPDATE:
Added [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4nstr575/) to demonstrate the problem. The spinner is not spinning when code execution is within a loop.

```
<img src="http://content.markitcdn.com/corporate/ResourceManager/9Iy-xMz_zHH-zXFAlhM-KA2/d/f/635151312565356632/Content/Images/Icons/General/spinner2.gif" alt="">
<script>
    console.log('entering loop')
    for (var i=0;i<300000000;i++) {}
    console.log('leaving loop')
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in a controller that fetched and displayed a list of databases from a SQL Server. I wanted the wait cursor to be displayed until the data was returned, but the UI was frozen instead. I solved it by toggling an `isWaiting` flag via a `$rootScope` method (which resulted in the wait cursor getting displayed in the view) and then clearing that flag in the callback at the end of the async process.

This isn't exactly what you're trying to do, but it might be close enough to adapt. You probably could use a method on `$scope` instead of `$rootScope` for your purposes, and have a div-level class (instead of html-level) that controlled whether or not a spinner image was displayed.

Disclaimer: This was used in a desktop app using node-webkit, as opposed to a normal browser. But I think this same basic approach would work in a normal browser too.

CSS:

```
html.wait, html.wait * {
  cursor: wait !important;
}
```

MainController:

```
// sets up a method that can be used from any controller
$rootScope.toggleWaiting = function (isWaiting) {
    $rootScope.isWaiting = isWaiting;
    $('html')[isWaiting ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass']('wait');
};
```

DatabasesController:

```
.controller('databasesController', ['$rootScope', '$scope', function($rootScope, $scope) {

    $rootScope.toggleWaiting(true);

    var SqlServerHelper = require("SqlServerHelper");
    var sqlServerHelper = new SqlServerHelper(/* sensitive config info removed */);

    sqlServerHelper.getDatabases(function(err, results) {
        /* standard error handling removed */
        $scope.$apply(function() {
            $rootScope.toggleWaiting(false);
            $scope.databaseList = results;
        });
    });

}])
```

P.S. One final thought: If the gif still appears frozen, maybe use `$timeout` from your controller to kick off the long-running process, so it happens on an async background thread. (Although I would think that's how it would work behind the scenes anyway, depending on what exactly it's doing that takes so long... presumably calling an external resource asynchronously to begin with?)

Comment: Nope, not calling an external resource, since as you said it's asynchronous. The problem is that angular compiles DOM _synchroniously_ and doesn't return control to browser during that time. Your solution seems to be targeting the asynchronous situation as opposed to what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I have implemented a loader on my angular apps. It's really simple. I use the less file below, it can easily be translated into CSS:

```
.loader{
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
    z-index: 9999999999;

    i{
        font-size:80px;
        height:80px;
        width:82px;
        color:#fff;
        display:block;
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align:middle;
        margin: auto;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;
    }
}
```

Then you can add this html into your ng-view:

```
<div class="loader show">
    <i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-fw fa-spin"></i>
</div>
```

Note that I am using font-awesome and not a .gif file for the loading animation.

Here are some sources to do further reading:

http://fontawesome.io

http://blog.madnesslabs.net/madness-u-package-managers/ <- Blog post from Madness Labs on how to use package managers to install dependencies like Font-Awesome, angular, angular-route, ect.

Answer (score 0):

Dont know about angular apps but for a browser, there a fiddle that is Worth a look... very less work for a good animation http://jsfiddle.net/qzLdjq3c/5/

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('.spinner').show();
    $(".spinner").hide();
});
```

Comment: there is no need to use jQuery and manipulate DOM in such simple case and mess it with angular. Simple css is enough.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a good candidate for [ng-cloak](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak)

the ng-cloak class is removed during compilation. Typically it is used with display: none, however you could also use it to display a spinner.

Comment: right.. your script is blocking the UI. never block the UI. Use $timeout or settimeout to break the computation into pieces.

Comment: Yes, but it's not my script. It's angular's. And this is exactly what I'm asking - a sensible way to break anuglar's linking phase into pieces.